# centimetre accuracy using IMU, is it possible?

Tags: sensors, imu, precise-positioning

I need to track hand movement, most importantly its vertical position to centimetre accuracy.

I've tried this with IMU MP6050 but the errors I get from double integration are huge.

Is there a way to get cm accuracy in position using the MP6050 or any other imu?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Ash, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0):

If contact-sensors can be used, cable pull sensors are nice (the hand can be attached to an end of the sensor with the other end to your "ground reference"). Ultrasonic / IR / Laser (based on range, noise and accuracy that you are looking for) for non-contact.

Basically, integral errors due to noise and drift will exclude acceleration sensors (eg. Accelerometer in the IMU) or velocity sensors. Barometric sensors could be used, but they may get affected due to pressure changes especially if you are using them for tracking small height changes.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many solutions depending on your environment.

For example, if there is a flat surface below, or above, you could use one of those sharp distance sensors.

If you are just somewhere with a scattered ground you would rely on some orientation point. A camera could read a fiducial as this gives angle and distance to the fiducial.